# Faster parsing of array in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, csv, request

I have a CSV file with 40 000 lines, i load ALL THE LINES in a array and i use this function to return a subarray with just the value i need... here is the code

```
<?php

//----------------------------------------------
function query_array($theArray,$theQuery,$col){

    $return = array();

    foreach($theArray as $subarray){
        if ($subarray[$col] == $theQuery) {
            $return[] = $subarray;
            }
    }

    return $return;
}

//----------------------------------------------
function parse_csv_file($csvfile) {

    $csvData = file_get_contents($csvfile);
    $lines = explode("\n", $csvData);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    return $array;
}

//----------------------------------------------
function echo_array($theArray) {

    $return = "";

    foreach ($theArray as $key => $value) {
        $result = implode(' ', $value);
        $return .= '(# '. $key .')-> '. $result .'<br/>';
    }

    return $return;

}

//----------------------------------------------
$starttime = microtime(TRUE);

$fileName = "the-path-to-my-file/PHOTOS.TXT";
$basename = basename($fileName);
$MyQuery = "8370336";
$myCol = 0;

echo 'Query : Find : '. $MyQuery . ' dans la collone : '. $myCol . ' du fichier : '. $basename .'<br/><br/>';

$outputArray = parse_csv_file($fileName);
$slimDownArray = query_array($outputArray, $MyQuery, $myCol);
echo echo_array($slimDownArray);

$endtime = microtime(TRUE);
$totaltime = $endtime - $starttime;
echo '<br/>Temp execution : '. round($totaltime,2) . ' second<br/>'."\n";

?>
```

so to get the 23 entry from the 40 000 line csv, it take 1.7 second... the question, can we make it faster ?, less that 1 sec ?

Comment: Do you know that you want the 23rd entry prior to loading the CSV file? If so you can limit how much of the CSV file you read in at the outset.

Comment: or if you can recognize the entry when you see it, there is no reason to save every line. you just loop through the lines and forget them until you find the one you need

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that is overkill unless this needs to be done often. without more information, we don't know that, but you are probably right.

Comment: @Tim it takes 1.7 seconds to find a _single record_ this way. He has 40k records! Database isn't overkill at all. It can be a lightweight DB, like SQLite. He'd get his result in a tiny fraction of the time.

Comment: the database frontend has to parse the csv too is all I am saying. if you are doing it extremely rarely, then I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @jszobody i dont what the #23 entry, i got 23 entrys from the 40 000 +

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage using csv file directly instead of DB is like reading cache file, i think it will be faster...overall !

Comment: I can read the csv file (files) ONCE and subset the array multiple time if i keep the read file in global array... i dont know what take more time... i put more timers...

Comment: @Tim If the question is how to make the search faster, the answer is absolutely "use a database instead".

Comment: @menardmam I think based on your last comment you should be definitely using a database.

Comment: @menardmam "i think [csv] will be faster overall" <-- Uh no, absolutely no. A DB will give you a result in a few milliseconds.

Comment: @Blazemonger agreed. I only wanted to say that you can definitely query a csv file directly in less than the time it is taking him.

Comment: 1.4 over 1.7 second if the READ/parsing of the file !

Comment: So @tim, your my men.... if i can definitively do that faster, can you show me the code ?, or tell me your way to do that... i am waiting no DB please ! all in php

Comment: @menardmam I don't know why I should help you do that. The others are right. If you don't want a database server, then there are PHP functions for SQLite.

Comment: I had redo it with fgetcsv instead of str_getcsv.. about as slow !

Comment: OK, then, no solution that going DB mysql... so sad ! :-( i will close the question !

Comment: I already code the solution to get the CSV file into a mysql DB using PDO... and all the request on DB result in crash server error 500 ! never had problem with file request !

Comment: @menardmam I said if you don't want mysql, use sqlite. It uses a database file direct on disk.

Comment: @menardmam and you don't even have to use php to generate the database file, there is a commandline utility for importing data from csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object or class approach would be better/more flexible but this approach should be faster than what you have.  I just used constants for several things.  The `$line` stuff is there only in case you care about the line number:

```
function query_csv($query, $col) {

    static $fp;

    if(!$fp) {
        $fp = fopen(CSV_NAME, 'r');
    }    
    $line = 0;
    $return = array();

    while(($data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, CSV_DELIM, CSV_ENC)) !== false) {
        if($data[$col] == $query) {
            //$return[$line] = $data; //if you want array keyed by line
            $return[] = $data;
        }
        $line++;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to initially load all the lines into an array. Just build the 'filtered' array at the start.

```
$field_delimiter = ",";  // or "|" or any other delimiter
function parse($file_in) {

    $fh = fopen($file_in, "r");
    $data_arr = array();
    while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, $field_delimiter)) !== false) {

         //add data into your array in here;
         //anytime you want to skip a line of data, just use:  continue;

    }
    return $data_arr;
}
```